# Why is ng-repeat not displaying parent key?

Tags: angularjs

I have some data set up like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
      weekDay: {
        monday: [{
          time: ''
        }],
        tuesday: [{
          time: ''
        }], 
        wednesday: [{
          time: ''
        }],
        thursday: [{
          time: ''
        }],
        friday: [{
          time: ''
        }],
        saturday: [{
          time: ''
        }],
        sunday: [{
          time: ''
        }]
      }
    }];
```

If I set up an ng-repeat like this...

```
<p ng-repeat="day in data.weekDay">{{day}}</p>
```

All I see is:

{"time":""}

{"time":""}

{"time":""}...

Why can't I see the parent key (individual days of the week)? How would I be able to use the days of the week in my repeater? (e.g. as a title in an h3 tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access `weekDay` property like `data.weekDay` as `$scope.data` is an array. Access it as `data[0].weekDay`.

```
<p ng-repeat="(day, timeObj) in data[0].weekDay">
    {{day}}
</p>
```

---

Otherwise change your data like this (which makes more sense I guess)

```
$scope.data = {
        weekDay: {...}
    };
```

and access it as `data.weekDay` in ng-repeat

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dghfcg42/)

Answer (score 0):

In the json the week day is an index, not a value. For example the monday it would be like below:

```
$scope.data = [
{
  weekDay: {
   dayname: 'monday',        
   timevalue : [{
      time: ''
    }],

    ... Rest of values ...
  }
}];
```

And the html like below

```
<p ng-repeat="day in data.weekDay">{{dayname}}</p>
```